# run command on TD Agent Admin Prompt

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, batch-file

I am trying to install a data collector tool name fluend on win 10. I am able to do it manually but now I try to automate this installation as this is going to install in large number of boxes.

My challenge is to pass any command as Administrator : Td-agent Command Prompt..
 https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/install-by-msi

Can you suggest how i can run any command as Administrator : Td-agent Command Prompt from Admin Command prompt or from a power shell Script. Below are the screen shot for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [PSexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to install MSI packages remotely. You can use CMD or PowerShell to run the below command.

`psexec \\ComputerName -u Domain\UserName -p Password -h cmd /c "msiexec /i \\ServerName\ShareName\td-agent.msi /qn /L*V LogFileName.log"`

Few things to keep in mind:

- MSI should support a silent install.
- The account you use to run needs admin rights.
- You should store the MSI package on a shared location which is accessible from all computers (if you have domain environment you can put in this path `\\DomainName.com\NetLogon`).

If you want to execute this on many computers then put all computer names in a text file and use PowerShell to run it on all computers.

```
get-content computername.txt | foreach {
       .\psexec \\$_ -u domain\username -p password -h cmd /c "msiexec /i \\ServerName\ShareName\td-agent.msi /qn /L*V LogFileName.log"
        if ($?) { Write-host "Command completed successfully."} else {Write-host "Command failed!"}
}
```

Let me know if you need further help or something doesn't work.

Comment: I dont have issue installing the msi...Once the msi is installed I need to run few commands in as Administrator : Td-agent Command Prompt. This is where i am having issue. I am able to run the batch file as :                                                                       call "C:\opt\td-agent\td-agent-prompt.bat" 
gem install fluent-plugin-kinesis-firehose
fluentd --reg-winsvc i , but this is running as Td-Agent however i want to run its as                                                                                                                          Td-agent Command Prompt

Comment: @user3544592 if you know where TD agent command is located on the system then you can use PSExec to run it remotely on any system. For Example if the command prompt is installed under system32  then this what your psexec would look like `psexec \\ComputerName -u Domain\UserName -p Password -h c:\windows\system32\TD-AgentCommandPrompt.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `cmd /k C:\opt\td-agent\td-agent-prompt.bat` to start a new command prompt with the files on the PATH. You can also just in Powershell do `$env:PATH+="C:\opt\td-agent\embedded\bin;"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:PATH + ";C:\opt\td-agent\embedded\bin", "Machine")

    #Test interactive process via background job (action seems to initiate config necessary for winsvc registration):
    
    $bkgndConfigInit=Start-Job -ScriptBlock { $env:PATH+="C:\opt\td-agent\embedded\bin" ; fluentd -c etc\td-agent\td-agent.conf } #launch interactive front end process as job which completes some one-time init
```